# Drawing images compensation algorithm

Tags: c, performance, bitmap, pixel, bmp

In some old/regular environments the only choice to render image is by using the base drawing functions

- `putpixel(x, y);` *(puts pixel in x/y location of canvas)*
- `lineto(x, y);`  *(draws a line to from offset to x/y location of canvas)*
- `moveto(x, y);` *(moves offset to x/y location of canvas)*
- `setpen(r, g, b, transp, size);`

But they are really slow, especially if a lot has to be drawn at once.

---

I am willing to invent a compensation algorithm that accords to this picture I exemplified:
[image]

What it does as you can see is predict where is more appropriate to use `lineto` instead `putpixel` to save iterations. In this example, it skips more than 50% of the iterations. (the red line indicates that this offset will not be drawn with putpixel, but is part of already-drawn line)
It decides whether vertical or horizontal line is better. It will be really hard and slow buffering if that has to be done with `sin/cosin` functionions to also determine the angle?

---

Is there any advice I can receive to simplify this work (or if there are already existing similar mechanisms), before I start?

Comment: As you need to set a color for all pixel, why just draw horizontal line is not efficient ?

Comment: that's a nice topic to play with, but you should know that on most architectures (especially on "old environments") a horizontal line is always the fastest way to bring anything on screen. Most architectures have some kind of frame buffer where ascending memory addresses correspond to the next x coordinate. If you reach the right border, the next address is just x=0, y+1. Some older architectures have interleaved bitplanes which means you need to modify bits in bytes if you want to have arbitrary pixels set.

Comment: Drawing line is much more efficient than putpixel, precisely. It will save another call of `setpen` and `putpixel` and even the whole iteration. This is why.. such algorithm must be created. It must be smart enough to determine where to use and what kind of line to use.

Comment: Why do you need sin and (or?) cos to 'determine the angle"? All you want to know is which one of a rectangle is larger, width or height.

Comment: @Jongware this is what this idea is trying to achieve. I was just wondering for such implementation with angle. More perfect appears to be. Because maybe there are cases where some arbitrary image's horizontal of homogenous pixels is larger (or the only for that matter) than the vertical/horizontal.

Comment: Given a line on an angle, the pixels impacted and the colour drawn to each such pixel is a property of the line drawing method (e.g. brezenham or something else) so any angled drawing will be a problem.

Comment: Yes. I know. `lineto` already uses BLA.

Comment: Why are you in "old environment"? If you do your pixel/line drawing into a memory image first (Bresenham can be used here too), can you then render the whole image map to the device in its most efficient way? That will save on slow device rendering, when you are, say, drawing a line across aleady rendered pixels. I suggest you think sideways.

Comment: Is this problem for academic purposes?  Usually the solution to this kind of problem is to use a buffer and just blit the whole thing.

I suggest checking out the API because it's highly unusual to have an optimized `lineto`, but not a blit.

Comment: Drawing directly to the video's buffer is definitely not portable and requires 3rd party resources and far than securer..

Answer (score 0):

What kind of crazy API is this where the processing involved to apply such an algorithm more than compensates for an API calling overhead? This is more restrictive than the tricks we had to use during the days of single-buffered 4-color CGA graphics!

There's no image blitter function whatsoever where you can draw to an offscreen buffer and blit it in advance to compensate for the slow drawing routines?

In any case, granting this kind of pathological example, what I'd first suggest trying instead is merely breaking down the image into horizontal scanlines and consolidated `putpixel` into a `lineto` calls within a single horizontal scanline. That might actually be better than what you're doing since it's more memory/cache-friendly, which may count more than reducing the number of API calls.

If that's not good enough and you want to try this full-blown route, something similar to this is often done in the 3D/gaming industry to compute efficient triangle strips for meshes to provide a slightly more compact rep. Example: http://www.codercorner.com/Strips.htm

Your algorithm has a very similar idea, but you don't need to bother with creating an adjacency structure since it's just neighboring pixels (up/down/left/right). You also want to prioritize neighbors going in the same direction (ex: if the previous neighbor is down, favor the up neighbor when possible).